# How do I draw an image which fits into an entire phone screen in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, svg, imageview

I need to have a background image (`bitmap` or a `SVG` resource) in the content area of my activity screen. I will be building some `UI` elements like button, images on top of this background image.

So my query is,

1. What should be the ideal width and height of the background image i need to use in order for the app to work consistently on all major phone screens
2. I use the RelativeLayout so that I can add some more UI elements programatically from my code. In this case what should I set the property of the ImageView for it to completely fit to the screen.
3. Is there any standard guide like this [Android iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html%20%20Iconography) for designing layout with background images that stretch width and height of the phone screen

Things that I tried that didn't work out include

**1.   Setting the adjustViewBounds = true for ImageView**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/manga_page_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

2. Programatically setting

   ```
   public class ScalingImages extends Activity {

   private ImageView imageView;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.test_margin);

       this.imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.news_image);

       // The image is coming from resource folder but it could also 
       // load from the internet or whatever
       Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img);
       Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

       // Get scaling factor to fit the max possible width of the ImageView
       float scalingFactor = this.getBitmapScalingFactor(bitmap);

       // Create a new bitmap with the scaling factor
       Bitmap newBitmap = Util.ScaleBitmap(bitmap, scalingFactor);

       // Set the bitmap as the ImageView source
       this.imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
   }

   private float getBitmapScalingFactor(Bitmap bm) {
       // Get display width from device
       int displayWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

       // Get margin to use it for calculating to max width of the ImageView
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
           (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)this.imageView.getLayoutParams();
       int leftMargin = layoutParams.leftMargin;
       int rightMargin = layoutParams.rightMargin;

       // Calculate the max width of the imageView
       int imageViewWidth = displayWidth - (leftMargin + rightMargin);

       // Calculate scaling factor and return it
       return ( (float) imageViewWidth / (float) bm.getWidth() );
   }
   }
   ```

where

```
public class Util {

    public static Bitmap ScaleBitmap(Bitmap bm, float scalingFactor) {
        int scaleHeight = (int) (bm.getHeight() * scalingFactor);
        int scaleWidth = (int) (bm.getWidth() * scalingFactor);

        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, scaleWidth, scaleHeight, true);
    }

}
```

I still haven't tried using the `SurfaceView` option as I assume it to be resource cruncher as it tries to load the image every time. I would like to know are there any better way to do this.

Comment: what about aspect ratio?

Comment: You have to set `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in xml file. And make sure that image should not be stretched so use 720*1280 size image for xhdpi and 480*800 and so on.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't stretch